# OPTIONS ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED when uploading file to s3

Tags: angularjs, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload an image to S3 using Angular and Laravel 5.1.

Angular first asks my server app for a presigned URL, then proceeds to upload the file using the signed request.

I'm getting the following OPTIONS error when the signature returns and then attempts to upload with it:

`OPTIONS https://s3.us-standard.amazonaws.com/my.resources/dog-aromatherapy.jpg?x-a…Signature=b3ef83... net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

my.resources S3 Bucket CORS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Laravel:

```
public function signature(Request $request)
{

    ...get Request filename and filetype...

    $s3Client = new S3Client([
        'region'  => 'us-standard',
        'version' => 'latest'
    ]);

    $options = [
        'Bucket'     => getenv('AWS_S3_BUCKET'),
        'Key'        => $file_name,
        'Expires'   => 60,
        'ContentType' => $file_type,
        'ACL' => 'public-read'
    ];

    $cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('PutObject', $options);

    $s_request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');

    $pre_signedUrl = (string) $s_request->getUri();

    return response()->json(
        [
            'signed_request' => $pre_signedUrl,
            'url' => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/' . getenv('AWS_S3_BUCKET') . '/' . $file_name
        ]
    );
}
```

**What gives?** I have a valid CORS config on the correct S3 bucket, and am getting a seemingly presigned signature to then allow a file upload...

---

Clicking into the OPTIONS error, headers are as follows:

```
x-amz-acl:public-read
X-Amz-Content-Sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
X-Amz-Algorithm:AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
X-Amz-Credential:AKIA/20160614/us-standard/s3/aws4_request
X-Amz-Date:20160614T172559Z
X-Amz-SignedHeaders:host
X-Amz-Expires:1200
X-Amz-Signature:b3ef836...
```

Comment: But your `CORS` headers don't allow `OPTIONS` which is the failure? I only see `GET/PUT/POST` but it needs `OPTIONS` too

Comment: Adding `<AllowedMethod>OPTIONS</AllowedMethod>` to s3 CORS gives error `Found unsupported HTTP method in CORS config. Unsupported method is OPTIONS`

Comment: There's actually a different way to do this in S3. I'm not an aficionado with S3, but I know that when you create the bucket, you have the ability to choose `HEAD + OPTIONS` and not only `HEAD`. I don't know how to modify it after you've created the bucket, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in this line of header

```
X-Amz-Credential:AKIA/20160614/us-standard/s3/aws4_request
```

Change that `"us-standard"` to `"us-east-1"` and it will work

Amazon S3 renamed the US Standard region to the US East (N. Virginia) region to be consistent with AWS regional naming conventions.

In this code

```
$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('PutObject', $options);
```

change options to "params"

Comment: Now it's uploading the file, but the file on `s3` is 0 bytes. Did it fake upload?

Comment: Well that is a different issue in the code, by any chance is your file getting uploaded twice? The authentication issue has been fixed as the credentials are working now and authentication is happening

Comment: In this code $cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('PutObject', $options); change options to "params" and the see if it works?

Comment: seems to upload now, but it's showing a weird white mini box rather than the image, yet the file size `28k` and content type are correct. Posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37820059/uploading-presigned-image-to-s3-from-angular-image-does-not-appear

Comment: Ok I will take a look into the new question. But mark my answer as correct for this question

Comment: I answered your new question too