# Uploading presigned image to s3 from Angular - image does not appear

Tags: angularjs, image, laravel, amazon-s3

I'm using Angular to upload images to s3 bucket, using a presigned URL received from my Laravel server.

The file seems to upload fine with the correct content types. If I click on the s3 file after the Angular upload `PUT`'s to s3, I get:

```
Object: dog-aromatherapy.jpg

  Bucket:   dderesources
  Name: dog-aromatherapy.jpg
  Link: This is a public link -> https://s3.amazonaws.com/dde.resources/dog-aromatherapy.jpg
  Size: 28660
  Last Modified:    Tue Jun 14 14:51:13 GMT-400 2016
  Owner:    myusername
  ETag: f478788943af2296223a0f45a9c50610
  Expiry Date:  None
  Expiration Rule:  N/A
```

Meta data is correct as `image/jpeg`:

[image]

But the actual file size is `27.9kb`, meaning the `headers` size of `28.6kb` is expecting an extra ~700b or so that is missing...

[image]

---

When I click on the image to view, it shows a white minibox:

[image]

Try it yourself: https://s3.amazonaws.com/dderesources/dog-aromatherapy.jpg

**Angular Upload Code**:

```
var upload_file = function (file, response) {

    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('image', file);

    return $http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: response.signed_request,
        data: formData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': file.type
        },
        cache: true
    });
};
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the period "." from your bucket name and make it some thing like this this will resolve the issue

> dde-resources

As bucket names with a period "." does not go very well when you are using resigned URL's in your code.

And use below statement in your angular code

```
processData: false
```

Comment: changed to `dderesources` and this did not solve it. The file on the left size is `27.9kb`, but when I click `view properties` on the file, and shows size `28660`, or `28.6kb`. If I download the file and try to open it, it says `It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn't recognize.`

Comment: try Changing that http to https in Angular upload code.

Comment: Angular `$http` will change as needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839524/how-to-use-https-in-angularjs

Comment: From where the file gets uploaded? From Ec2 instance or the user uploads the file?

Comment: User drags the image on my Angular app. When this happens, 1st) I make a sign request to my laravel app, which returns presignedURL, 2nd) I make upload to S3 using that signed request, and append the image binary

Comment: Still digging out the solution for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114679/discussion-between-growler-and-code-pro9081).